# android getSystemService error with extends BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I have 2 activities

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ..............
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ..............
    ..............
    }
}

public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver{

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        ..............
        ..............
    }


    public String getCellData() {

        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) ***getSystemService***(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        GsmCellLocation cellLocation = (GsmCellLocation) telephonyManager.getCellLocation();

        ..............
        ..............

        return someString;
    }
```

I want to get the return string from `getCellData` to `public void onReceive`. There is a error on **getSystemService** in `getCellData()`. What can I do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`getSystemService()` is a method on `Context`. `BroadcastReceiver` does not inherit from `Context`. However, you are passed a `Context` into `onReceive()`. So, call `getSystemService()` on that `Context` parameter.

Comment: Can you explain how to call getSystemService() on Context parameter. I am new to android. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing context in `onReceive()` method just call it using that context like

`context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);`