# Alarm with Notification - No error, but not showing

Tags: java, android, notifications, alarm

I'm trying to make an Alarm with Notification in Android Studio, i try [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43069188/android-getsystemservice-error-with-extends-broadcastreceiver) but i got error "Force Close". there is no error message in Log Cat. please help me to find this problem. my complete code [My Complete Code is here](https://github.com/hendroprwk08/MySubmission05).

```
public class MyAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Mine", "Set Daily");

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications_white)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Hello World!");

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(001, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you haven't included the Broadcast Receiver in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver 
    android:name="MyAlarm" >
</receiver>
```

Comment: already put in manifest 

<receiver android:name=".MyAlarm" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"/>